# Internet Explorer 10 | Focus Class | Placeholder Padding Issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-10

I have a strange issue in Internet Explorer 10.

It happens when you add/ remove a focus class. The placeholder text is misaligned vertically.

This does not happen if you use a focus selector. Unfortunately I can't use this approach.

**Here is an example:**

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input');

input.addEventListener('click', function () {
    this.classList.add('inputFocus');
});

input.addEventListener('blur', function () {
    this.classList.remove('inputFocus');
});
```

```css
body {
    padding-top: 20px;
}

input {
    padding: 11px 11px 11px 44px;
}

.inputFocus {
    margin-top: -10px;
    padding: 21px 11px 21px 44px;
}
```

```html
   <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
```

Cheers!